# Change "ROOT_URLCONF" in Django depending on site

Tags: django, apache

I just need some advice pointing me into the right direction using Django with multiple sites / clients.

Basically depending on the domain name I want to use multiple sites with only one Django instance.

For example a directory structure.

```
mysite/
     manage.py
     settings.py
     client1/
          url.py
     client2/
          url.py
```

So what I am thinking is, inside settings.py depending on the domain name I can change the

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.clientx.urls'
```

The site will match about 95% so I don't see the point of changing all other settings as well.

How would I do this? I did go through site management in the Django documentation although it seems like an overkill for what I want to accomplish.

Also keep in mind I am using Apache with "django.wsgi".

Comment: Check https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultiHostMiddleware

Comment: Thanks Rohan, seems like this will solve my problem.